# How do I tell WCF to skip verification of the certificate?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, http, https, certificate

Trying to make a [web service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) call to an [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) endpoint in my [Silverlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight) application results in this error: "Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]"

The same problem as was posted here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/4c19271a-f5e6-4659-9e06-b556dbdcaf82/

So, one of the suggestions was this: "The other issue might be that the cert name and the machine name don't agree, and this is causing [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) to have fits. If this is the case, you can tell WCF to skip verification of the cert."

Well, I **do** get a certificate error because this is just a demo server.

Here's how I set up my client:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
_ws = new AnnotationService.AnnotationClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(myAddress));
```

How can I tell WCF to skip the verification?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You might be able to achieve this in Silverlight by **allowing cross-domain communication** between the web server the hosts the Silverlight application and the remote WCF service.

In that case you need to place a [**clientaccesspolicy.xml**](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html) file at the root of the domain where the WCF service is hosted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">
        <domain uri="http://*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Here's what [MSDN states about this approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(v=vs.95).aspxhttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(v=vs.95).aspx):

> To allow access to an HTTPS service
>   from any Silverlight control hosted
>   over HTTP application, you need to put
>   the *<domain uri=”http://*” />* element
>   inside your *<allow-from>* element.

I haven't tried this myself but it could be worth a shot. Also be sure to check out the following resources for more details:

- [Making a Service Available Across Domain Boundaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(v=vs.95).aspxhttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(v=vs.95).aspx)
- [Configuring Web Service Usage in Silverlight Clients](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197941(v=vs.95).aspx)

---

### Disabling X.509 certificate validation in .NET

For .NET applications this sample WCF configuration will disable validation of both whether the certificate is trusted and whether it is still valid on the client:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DisableServiceCertificateValidation">
            <clientCredentials>
                <serviceCertificate>
                    <authentication certificateValidationMode="None"
                                    revocationMode="NoCheck" />
                </serviceCertificate>
            </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/MyService"
        behaviorConfiguration="DisableServiceCertificateValidation"
        binding="wsHttpBinding"
        contract="MyNamespace.IMyService"
        name="MyServiceWsHttp" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**An alternative solution** is to provide custom logic to validate the X.509 certificate provided by the service. In that case you will have to modifiy the configuration file according to the following:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DisableServiceCertificateValidation">
            <clientCredentials>
                <serviceCertificate>
                    <authentication certificateValidationMode="Custom"
                                    customCertificateValidatorType="MyCertificateValidator, Client"
                                    revocationMode="NoCheck" />
                </serviceCertificate>
            </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/MyService"
        behaviorConfiguration="DisableServiceCertificateValidation"
        binding="wsHttpBinding"
        contract="MyNamespace.IMyService"
        name="MyServiceWsHttp" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Then create a class that derives from [X509CertificateValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.selectors.x509certificatevalidator.aspx) to implement your custom validation logic.

```
public class MyCertificateValidator : X509CertificateValidator
{
    public override void Validate(X509Certificate2 certificate)
    {
        // Add custom validation logic
        // Throw an exception to fail validation
    }
}
```

As always, you can find [a more detailed example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354512.aspx) up on MSDN.

Comment: Will state the obvious: the code above is for the WFC client ;)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the answer to be more specific.

Comment: Do you know of a simple way to skip the hostname check as well? If they do not match, it will still fail with just these settings.

Comment: I am not aware of any configuration option in WCF to explicitly turn hostname validation off. In that cause you could provide your own custom certificate validator, and simply let all certificates pass. I updated my answer with an example of how to do that.

Comment: Unrecognized element 'behaviors' in service reference configuration. Note that only a subset of the Windows Communication Foundation configuration functionality is available in Silverlight.

Comment: This does not work in Silverlight 4 because of the lack of support for <behaviors>, as Broken Pipe stated.  Does this work in a previous version of Silverlight?

Comment: @BrokenPipe @Keith You guys are absolutely right. Silverlight does *not* include the classes showed in my example. I updated my answer with a possible solution for Silverlight and kept the original content for the record.

Comment: You can even do this programatically - the problem seems that if the chain of certificates back to the root isn't found - the custom Validator doesn't even get called. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This does not look like an certificate validation error.  It looks like a webservice configuration error.   Can you post the config for your endpoint on the server?

WCF services don't support SSL by default, you need to enable transport security by creating a binding configuration and pointing your endpoint to it with the bindingConfiguration attribute.

Here is a sample binding configuration that supports SSL:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="SecureTransport">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

and your endpoint config would look like this:

```
<endpoint address=""
   binding="basicHttpBinding"
   bindingConfiguration="SecureTransport"
   contract="MyServices.IWebService" />
```