# How to stop certificate errors temporarily with WCF services

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am testing an early release of a WCF web service I have created. On the client side when I use VS to 'add service reference' that all works.

But when I try to use the service I get the error,

> ```
> Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure
> channel with authority **
> ```

Where the stars represent the IP address of the server.

Anyway on the server there is a security certificate but it has been self generated just for testing, so I am not concerned about certificate errors for the moment.

On the client side an app.config has been generated for me,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BindingName" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="***************"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BindingName"
                contract="***************" name="BindingName">
                <identity>
                    <servicePrincipalName value="***************" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

So what settings do I need to change to temporarily ignore certificate errors?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Set the CertificatePolicy PRIOR to initializing your WCF service on the client. Here's how (just make a call to the SetCertificatePolicy() method once)

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Sets the cert policy.
    /// </summary>
    private static void SetCertificatePolicy()
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ValidateRemoteCertificate;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Certificate validation callback 
    /// </summary>
    private static bool ValidateRemoteCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors error)
    {
        if (error == SslPolicyErrors.None)
        {
           return true;   // already determined to be valid
        }

        switch (cert.GetCertHashString())
        {
           // thumbprints/hashes of allowed certificates (uppercase)
           case "066CF9CAD814DE2097D368F22D3A7D398B87C4D6":
           case "5B82C96685E3A20079B8CE7AFA32554D55DB9611":

              Debug.WriteLine("Trusting X509Certificate '" + cert.Subject + "'");
              return true;

           default:
              return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice comment - "Remotes the certificate validate." :P

Comment: Hehe, I didn't noticed before. It did look odd. I changed it. Thanks!

Comment: It seems like my ValidateRemoteCertificate is never called... any clues why?

Comment: @guiomie (answer to old question) You need to execute `SetCertificatePolicy()` once :-)

Comment: I added in a safety check for thumbprints (I chose thumbprint as opposed to serial number because that is the value shown as 'Certificate hash' in IIS). For a real quick and dirty solution you can just return true, but it is better to check the thumbprint of a trusted cert. I need to be able to run this in production so I can have a hosts file with a `10.0.0.1   www.example.com` entry to bypass cloudflare (who provides our SSL).

Comment: this is a global setting for your whole application, not per client

Answer (score 18):

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <servicePointManager checkCertificateName="false" checkCertificateRevocationList="false" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

This works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Modifying web.config worked for me

I did it using Steve Ellinger's answer and some googling.
Essentially, I had to:

- tell manager of HTTP connections to use certificate without matching certificate name with server host name, and without checking whether the certificate has been revoked
- modify endpoint behavior on client side in order to turn off certificate validation

Here are the web.config snippets...

```
<configuration>

  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <servicePointManager checkCertificateName="false" checkCertificateRevocationList="false" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint ... behaviorConfiguration="DisableServiceCertificateValidation" />
    </client>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DisableServiceCertificateValidation">
          <clientCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="None"
                              revocationMode="NoCheck" />
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps. I've found a bit extra info, see [WCF Gotcha: Disabling SSL Validation](http://webservices20.blogspot.co.nz/2008/12/wcf-gotcha-disabling-ssl-validation.html)

Answer (score 4):

Check the answer to this question:

[How do I tell WCF to skip verification of the certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338385/how-do-i-tell-wcf-to-skip-verification-of-the-certificate)

it gives two possible solutions:
 1. using just config entries on the client side 
 or 
 2. use a custom certificate validator that uses both code and config entries

Answer (score 4):

You could also override with this oneliner.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
```

Simply paste it into the generated WCF client constructor in `Reference.cs`

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class WebQuoteServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<Corp.Legal.Webservices.ServiceReference1.IWebQuoteService>, Corp.Legal.Webservices.ServiceReference1.IWebQuoteService {

    public WebQuoteServiceClient()
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
    }
```