# Assistance modifying app.config to let client app ignore server's expired certificate (good cert, just expired out of date)

Tags: .net, xml, wcf

Can anyone tell me where to modify my app.config so that when the app launches and connects to my server so that the app will just ignore the fact that the X.509 certificate on the server has expired?

I was attempting to just install a new SSL certificate from a known CA to replace the old one, but apparently the software manufacturer has the thumbprint of the old certificate hard coded somewhere that I can't find.  So, I'm left with just trying to get the client app to bypass the expired certificate so I can interact with the system.

Note: this is an out-of-date system used only for old record lookups, it's safe and secured from the internet, it's only used in a local environment where security is not an issue.

I tried to add XML code that I found from a previous discussion, but it doesn't seem to work.  I also don't have a `<system.net>` element in my app.config, so I was just shooting from the hip.

What I tried ...

```
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <servicePointManager checkCertificateName="None" checkCertificateRevocationList="NoCheck" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>
```

Here's my current app.config file for the client app ...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="exceptionHandling" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Configuration.ExceptionHandlingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0ccaa1d06491a513" />
    <section name="securityCryptographyConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography.Configuration.CryptographySettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0ccaa1d06491a513" />
    <section name="informationMonitoringSynchronization" type="System.Configuration.NameValueFileSectionHandler" />
    <section name="assembliesToJIT" type="System.Configuration.NameValueFileSectionHandler" />
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0ccaa1d06491a513" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WCF_Base_URL" value="net.tcp://localhost:{0}/Allscripts.Homecare/Services/{1}/{2}" />
    <add key="WCF_Hosting_Binding_Configuration_Name" value="Mfg.Industry.NetTcpBinding.Configuration.Open" />
    <add key="WCF_Hosting_Binding_Type" value="NetTcpBinding" />
    <add key="SLPingTimeout" value="2" />
    <add key="WCF_Hosting_Start_Port" value="2222" />
    <add key="WCF_Hosting_End_Port" value="9199" />
  </appSettings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="bin" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <exceptionHandling>
    <exceptionPolicies>
      <add name="Authentication Exception Policy">
        <exceptionTypes>
          <add name="AuthenticationException" type="Mfg.Industry.Security.Framework.Facade.AuthenticationException, Mfg.Industry.Security.Framework.Facade, Version=17.2.0.163, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5afe0c9031f3768" postHandlingAction="NotifyRethrow">
            <exceptionHandlers />
          </add>
          <add name="Exception" type="System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" postHandlingAction="NotifyRethrow">
            <exceptionHandlers />
          </add>
        </exceptionTypes>
      </add>
      <add name="Unhandled Exception Policy">
        <exceptionTypes>
          <add name="Exception" type="System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" postHandlingAction="NotifyRethrow">
            <exceptionHandlers>
            </exceptionHandlers>
          </add>
          <add name="IndustryException" type="Mfg.Industry.IndustryException, Mfg.Industry.Lib, Version=17.2.0.163, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5afe0c9031f3768" postHandlingAction="NotifyRethrow">
            <exceptionHandlers>
            </exceptionHandlers>
          </add>
        </exceptionTypes>
      </add>
      <add name="User Services Exception Policy">
        <exceptionTypes>
          <add name="Exception" type="System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" postHandlingAction="None">
            <exceptionHandlers>
            </exceptionHandlers>
          </add>
        </exceptionTypes>
      </add>
    </exceptionPolicies>
  </exceptionHandling>
  <securityCryptographyConfiguration>
    <hashProviders>
      <add algorithmType="System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" saltEnabled="false" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmProvider, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="MD5CryptoServiceProvider" />
    </hashProviders>
  </securityCryptographyConfiguration>
  <informationMonitoringSynchronization>
    <add key="BatchSize" value="15" />
    <add key="CompressionEnabled" value="True" />
    <add key="MultithreadingEnabled" value="False" />
  </informationMonitoringSynchronization>
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>
  <assembliesToJIT>
    <add key="MfgIndustrySecurityCommon" value="Mfg.Industry.Security.Common" />
    <add key="MfgIndustrySecurityFramework" value="Mfg.Industry.Security.Framework" />
    <add key="MfgIndustrySecurityWebServicesClient" value="Mfg.Industry.Security.WebServices.Client" />
    <add key="MfgIndustrySecurityFrameworkFacade" value="Mfg.Industry.Security.Framework.Facade" />
    <add key="MfgIndustrySecurityAdministrationCommon" value="Mfg.Industry.Security.Administration.Common" />
    <add key="MfgIndustrySynchronization" value="Mfg.Industry.Synchronization" />
    <add key="MfgIndustrySynchronizationData" value="Mfg.Industry.Synchronization.Data" />
    <add key="MfgIndustryDFAClient" value="Mfg.Industry.DFA.Client" />
    <add key="MfgIndustryDFAFramework" value="Mfg.Industry.DFA.Framework" />
    <add key="EligibilityWebClient" value="Mfg.Industry.Eligibility.WebClient" />
    <add key="InformationMonitoring" value="Mfg.Industry.InformationMonitoring" />
    <add key="EligibilityClient" value="Mfg.Industry.Eligibility.Client" />
    <add key="SplitBillingRule" value="Mfg.Industry.SplitBillingRule" />
    <add key="EventManagerClient" value="Mfg.Industry.EventManager.Client" />
    <add key="MfgIndustrySanctionImportClient" value="Mfg.Industry.SanctionImport.Client" />
    <add key="MfgIndustryTestInterfaces" value="Mfg.Industry.TestInterfaces" />
    <add key="MfgIndustryOpenAPIClient" value="Mfg.Industry.OpenAPI.Client" />
    <add key="MfgIndustryCommonDefinitionData" value="Mfg.Industry.Common.DefinitionData" />
    <add key="InfomaticsMisc" value="Infomatics2.Win.Misc.v6.1, Version=6.1.20061.28, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb" />
    <add key="InfomaticsGrid" value="Infomatics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v6.1, Version=6.1.20061.28, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb" />
    <add key="InfomaticsEditors" value="Infomatics2.Win.UltraWinEditors.v6.1, Version=6.1.20061.28, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb" />
    <add key="InfomaticsFolio" value="Infomatics2.Win.UltraWinFolio.v6.1, Version=6.1.20061.28, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb" />
    <add key="InfomaticsFolio63" value="Infomatics2.Win.UltraWinFolio.v6.3, Version=6.3.20063.1091, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb" />
    <add key="InfomaticsTab" value="Infomatics2.Win.UltraWinTabControl.v6.1, Version=6.1.20061.28, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb" />
    <add key="InfomaticsWin" value="Infomatics2.Win.v6.1, Version=6.1.20061.28, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb" />
    <add key="InfomaticsTree" value="Infomatics2.Win.UltraWinTree.v6.1, Version=6.1.20061.28, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb" />
    <add key="InfomaticsShared" value="Infomatics2.Shared.v6.1, Version=6.1.20061.28, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb" />
    <add key="DevExpressUtils" value="DevExpress.Utils, Version=2.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=79868b8147b5eae4" />
    <add key="DevExpressEditors" value="DevExpress.XtraEditors, Version=2.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=79868b8147b5eae4" />
    <add key="CommonControls" value="Mfg.Industry.Forms.Controls" />
    <add key="MfgIndustryDFAClientData" value="Mfg.Industry.DFA.Client.Data" />
    <add key="MfgIndustryDFAClientDataFacade" value="Mfg.Industry.DFA.Client.Data.Facade" />
    <add key="MfgIndustryDFAClientSharedInterfaces" value="Mfg.Industry.DFA.Client.SharedInterfaces" />
    <add key="InformationMonitoringData" value="Mfg.Industry.InformationMonitoring.Data" />
    <add key="Eligibility" value="Mfg.Industry.Eligibility" />
    <add key="EligibilityCommon" value="Mfg.Industry.Eligibility.Common" />
    <add key="OnboardAndStatusConfiguration" value="Mfg.Industry.EventManager.OnboardAndStatusConfiguration" />
    <add key="EventManagerClientCommon" value="Mfg.Industry.EventManager.Client.Common" />
    <add key="EventManagerCommon" value="Mfg.Industry.EventManager.Common" />
    <add key="MfgIndustryFormsControls" value="Mfg.Industry.Forms.Controls" />
    <add key="MfgIndustryHelpManagerHelpClient" value="Mfg.Industry.HelpManager.HelpClient" />
    <add key="MfgIndustryPayrollCommon" value="Mfg.Industry.Payroll.Common" />
    <add key="MfgIndustryReportCommon" value="Mfg.Industry.Report.Common" />
  </assembliesToJIT>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="Mfg.Industry.NetTcpBinding.Configuration.Open" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <loggingConfiguration name="Logging Application Block" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General" logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch="true">
    <listeners>
      <add listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.CustomTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0ccaa1d06491a513" traceOutputOptions="None" type="Mfg.Industry.Plugin.Diagnostics.DebugTraceListener, Mfg.Industry.Plugin.Diagnostics" name="DebugTraceListener" initializeData="" formatter="" />
    </listeners>
    <categorySources>
      <add switchValue="All" name="General" />
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
      <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events">
        <listeners>
          <add name="DebugTraceListener" />
        </listeners>
      </allEvents>
      <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category" />
      <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings" />
    </specialSources>
  </loggingConfiguration>
</configuration>
```

If someone could help me figure out which element I need to call, and what to actually put there to completely ignore the expired X.509 certificate on the server, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "Expired" is clearly not "good". https://stackoverflow.com/a/18608619/11182

Comment: For Dotnetframework project, the below code might be useful, ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (a, b, c, d) => true; For Core project, it depends on your code.

Comment: Thank you, @AbrahamQian ... unfortunately I do not have access to the code, it is an app compiled by a former developer, now defunct.  I'm just trying to edit either the web.config or the individual Windows Service app.config files so that the client app will not check the certificate validation at all.  Somehow the original developer encoded the thumbprint of the expired certificate into the application communication. I've tried binding a new, not expired, trusted cert to IIS, but the client app is still trying to validate the thumbprint of the old cert. I have no idea where to change that.

Comment: When you replace the certificate of the server, first install the certificate in the trusted root certificate authority of the server(certlm.msc), then install the certificate in the trusted root certificate authority on the client side(certlm.msc). In my experience, your server just uses certificate to encrypt communication, and does not use the certificate to verify the client, so there is no logic to verify the server's certificate fingerprint. We only need to ensure that the server certificate is installed on the trusted root certificate authority on the client.