# .net client invoke JAX-WS webservice with X509 certificate and username/password authentication

Tags: c#, web-services, app-config, x509certificate, webservice-client

I've got a problem with using JAX-WS Webservice from .net client.
I'm able to open connection to WS but when I try to use any method then I got this errors:

First error I've get was:

`Identity check failed for outgoing message. The expected DNS identity of the remote endpoint was 'amms.someDomain.com' but the remote endpoint provided DNS claim '*.someDomain.com'. If this is a legitimate remote endpoint, you can fix the problem by explicitly specifying DNS identity '*.someDomain.com' as the Identity property of EndpointAddress when creating channel proxy.`

my app.config seems like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="SrvPortBinding">
                <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Basic128" authenticationMode="UserNameForCertificate"
                    requireDerivedKeys="false" securityHeaderLayout="Strict" includeTimestamp="true"
                    keyEntropyMode="CombinedEntropy" messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt"
                    messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10"
                    requireSignatureConfirmation="false">
                    <localClientSettings cacheCookies="true" detectReplays="true"
                        replayCacheSize="900000" maxClockSkew="00:05:00" maxCookieCachingTime="Infinite"
                        replayWindow="00:05:00" sessionKeyRenewalInterval="10:00:00"
                        sessionKeyRolloverInterval="00:05:00" reconnectTransportOnFailure="true"
                        timestampValidityDuration="00:05:00" cookieRenewalThresholdPercentage="60" />
                    <localServiceSettings detectReplays="true" issuedCookieLifetime="10:00:00"
                        maxStatefulNegotiations="128" replayCacheSize="900000" maxClockSkew="00:05:00"
                        negotiationTimeout="00:01:00" replayWindow="00:05:00" inactivityTimeout="00:02:00"
                        sessionKeyRenewalInterval="15:00:00" sessionKeyRolloverInterval="00:05:00"
                        reconnectTransportOnFailure="true" maxPendingSessions="128"
                        maxCachedCookies="1000" timestampValidityDuration="00:05:00" />
                    <secureConversationBootstrap />
                </security>
                <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
                    messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10" writeEncoding="utf-8">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="98192" maxArrayLength="916384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="94096" maxNameTableCharCount="916384" />
                </textMessageEncoding>
                <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="9524288"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="965536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="965536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                    realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true" requireClientCertificate="false" />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://amms.someDomain.com:443/mmew1/Srv"
          binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="SrvPortBinding"
          contract="InfoMedica1.Srv" name="SrvPort" >

      </endpoint>            
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

`

then I changed this:

```
<client>
      <endpoint address="https://amms.someDomain.com:443/mmew1/Srv"
          binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="SrvPortBinding"
          contract="InfoMedica1.Srv" name="SrvPort" >

      </endpoint>            
    </client>
```

to:

```
<client>
      <endpoint address="https://amms.someDomain.com:443/mmew1/Srv"
          binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="SrvPortBinding"
          contract="InfoMedica1.Srv" name="SrvPort" >
        <identity>
          <dns value="*.someDomain.com"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>            
    </client>
```

And now I've got exception :
`An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.`
**inner exception :**`Invalid Security Header`

Did anyone got that kind of error and got it working?
Can this error occurs because this `*` char in `*.someDomain.com`?

I've checked time on server and client side is the same. Webservice worked correctly before add this X509 and username/password authentication.

If any further information needed pls ask in comments:)

**Edit:**

When I tryed to disable Service Certificate Validation like that:

```
<client>
      <endpoint address="https://amms.someDomain.com:443/mmew1/Srv"
          binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="SrvPortBinding"
          contract="InfoMedica1.Srv" name="SrvPort" behaviorConfiguration="DisableServiceCertificateValidation">
        <identity>
          <dns value="*.someDomain.com"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>            
    </client>
```

Exception occurs:

```
There is no endpoint behavior named 'DisableServiceCertificateValidation'
```

Thanks for advance:)

Comment: Have you tried using "someDomain.com"? Have you tried using "amms.someDomain.com" just as a test? Have you tried disabling the certificate security checks as a test? Go look at the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338385/how-do-i-tell-wcf-to-skip-verification-of-the-certificate

Comment: First of all thanks for even trying help:)
yes I've tryed using `someDomain.com` and `amms.someDomain.com` it's changed nothing. I've made edit of question about third question asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with webservice. Guy who written it changed something not sure what exactly but it started to work:)

Maybe someone have similar problem so here it is ;)

Thanks for help all interested;)