# invalid certificate using wcf client

Tags: wcf, certificate, wshttpbinding, transport-security

I created a simple wcf service to be deployed on iis with this web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel"
          switchValue="Verbose"
          propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
                <add name="sdt"
                       type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                       initializeData= "log.e2e" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
         <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="WcfService1.Service1">
             <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                 bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpointBinding"
                 name="wsHttpEndpoint" contract="WcfService1.IService1">
             </endpoint>

             <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
                 name="MexHttpsBindingEndpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
         </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding">
                <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                <serviceCredentials>
                    <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Windows" />
                </serviceCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

I was following this example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354508%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Except the membership authentication. I installed the certificate on my client machine and on the server machine according with the procedure. If I browse the service, a certificate problem is shown, but anyway I can go to the not recommended site and I can see the wsdl. Using a wcf client, it throws an error "Could not establish a trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel". But using WCFStorm www.wcfstorm.com/, it works.

I don't know if it's always necessary to validate certificate from client or if it's a problem with the certificate. It's a testing environment... Thanks for any guide!!

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/479914/1373170 
See the "Disabling X.509 certificate validation in .NET" section on how to add the behavior