# Changing from BasicHTTPBinding to BasicHTTPSBinding not working

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I have a WCF service app and client app that I have written.  I have been using BasicHTTPBinding on both ends.

To be clear: This is NOT a web application.  The service is self-hosted in a PC application (NOT IIS).  All configuration of the endpoints on both the client and server are done in code, not in app.config.  In fact, to make sure, I have commented out the entire System.Servicemodel sections of app.config for both the client and server applications, and everything works great.  This is all using BasicHTTPBinding.

Now, I want to change everything to use HTTPS instead of HTTP, for security reasons.  I have changed what I thought I needed to change in my code, but it's not working.

## Original Code (This works fine!)

Server:

```
BasicHttpBinding _binding;            
Service1 _generalService;
ServiceHost _generalHost;

_binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
_binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1000000;
_generalService = new Service1(_dbConnParams, _imagePath, _registrationProvider, LicenseCount);
_generalHost = new ServiceHost(_generalService, new Uri("http://localhost:8000"));
_generalHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), _binding, "Service1");
_generalHost.Open();
```

Client:

```
internal static ToOrson.IService1 SetupService(string ServerAddress, TimeSpan? timeout = null)
{
    var myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    myBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1000000;

    if (timeout != null)
        myBinding.SendTimeout = (TimeSpan)timeout;

    string fullAddress = string.Format("http://{0}:8000/Service1", ServerAddress);
    var myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress(fullAddress);
    var myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ToOrson.IService1>(myBinding, myEndpoint);

    return myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
}

private async void TestButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var TestService = MainWindow.SetupService(ServerBox.Text);

    try
    {
        await TestService.TestConnectionAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception connException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Connection failed: " + connException.Message, "Error");
        return;
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Connection succeeded!", "Success");
}
```

## Code modified for HTTPS (This does NOT work)

Server:

```
BasicHttpsBinding _binding;            
Service1 _generalService;
ServiceHost _generalHost;

_binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
_binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1000000;
_generalService = new Service1(_dbConnParams, _imagePath, _registrationProvider, LicenseCount);
_generalHost = new ServiceHost(_generalService, new Uri("https://localhost:8000"));
_generalHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), _binding, "Service1");
_generalHost.Open();
```

Client:

```
internal static ToOrson.IService1 SetupService(string ServerAddress, TimeSpan? timeout = null)
{
    var myBinding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
    myBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1000000;

    if (timeout != null)
        myBinding.SendTimeout = (TimeSpan)timeout;

    string fullAddress = string.Format("https://{0}:8000/Service1", ServerAddress);
    var myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress(fullAddress);
    var myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ToOrson.IService1>(myBinding, myEndpoint);

    return myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
}

private async void TestButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var TestService = MainWindow.SetupService(ServerBox.Text);

    try
    {
        await TestService.TestConnectionAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception connException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Connection failed: " + connException.Message, "Error");
        return;
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Connection succeeded!", "Success");
}
```

Basically, I just changed BasicHTTPBinding to BasicHTTPSBinding and HTTP:// to HTTPS:// in all places in the code.

Here is the exception that I'm getting:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException "An error occurred while
making the HTTP request to https://localhost:8000/Service1. This could
be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured
properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by
a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server."
```

This exception is occurring on the client, on the call to TestService.TestConnectionAsync() (which is one of my OperationContracts).

Here are the inner exceptions:

> System.Net.WebException "The underlying connection was closed: An
>   unexpected error occurred on a send."
>
> System.IO.IOException "Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host."
>
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException "An existing connection was
>   forcibly closed by the remote host"

Yes, I updated my service reference after these changes.  Yes, I am targeting the .NET 4.5 framework.  I don't think it's a firewall issue, as I'm using the same port (8000) in both cases, and I already have that port open.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'd say that your client & server machines don't share a common trusted certificate for SSL and can't create a common encrypted channel. Although [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729700(v=vs.110).aspx) is for `wsHttpBinding`, the SSL configuration aspects also apply to `basicHttpBinding`.

Comment: Ugh!  For some reason, I was under the impression that certificates were only required when a web server and/or web browser was involved.  I didn't think that it was required for a self-hosted service, accessed by a dedicated client app.  It sounds like I may be wrong.  I am trying to make my server application's installation/configuration very easy for the end user, so I don't want them to be having to deal with certificates.  Is there any other simple way to ensure a secure connection between client and server?

Comment: @JoeMjr2 yes certificates are required for SSL and are the mechanism used for passing the client/server keys and other data needed to securely encrypt the data between the client and server.  See this for more info on SSL: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-work   Off the top of my head, I don't know of another simple way to secure the client/server connection. In most cases in .NET there is a way to disable or write your own certification validation, so that the client will accept the SSL connection regardless of if the cert if installed on the client.

Comment: Check out the section "An alternative solution is to provide custom logic to validate the X.509 certificate" in this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338385/how-do-i-tell-wcf-to-skip-verification-of-the-certificate

Comment: You can try [following SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274207/https-from-a-console-application/10373991#10373991) but it also requires certificates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WCF Error "This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013880/wcf-error-this-could-be-due-to-the-fact-that-the-server-certificate-is-not-conf)