# Disabling X.509 certificate validation in .NET with WCF service

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf

I am trying to set up message security in a WCF service and disable the X.509 certificate validation in the process. I'd like to validate the client with a username and password only and not validate the server at all. At least for now.

Referring to the first answer here:

[How do I tell WCF to skip verification of the certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338385/how-do-i-tell-wcf-to-skip-verification-of-the-certificate)

How do I achieve the following programmatically on the client?

```
<behavior name="DisableServiceCertificateValidation">
    <clientCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate>
            <authentication certificateValidationMode="Custom"
            customCertificateValidatorType="MyCertificateValidator, Client"
            revocationMode="NoCheck" />
         </serviceCertificate>
    </clientCredentials>
</behavior>
```

I have got this:

```
With myServiceClient.ClientCredentials
    .UserName.UserName = "username"
    .UserName.Password = "password"
    .ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.Custom
    .ServiceCertificate.Authentication.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck
End With
```

I can't work out how to set the "customCertificateValidatorType" and how to wire it to the MyCertificateValidator class.

Does this bypass the requirement of a client certificate, a server certificate or both?

Here is my server web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <trust level="Full"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>

     <services>

      <service name="HelloWorldService.HelloWorldService" behaviorConfiguration="BehaviourMessageSecurity">

        <endpoint address ="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="HelloWorld.IHelloWorldService" bindingConfiguration="BindingMessageSecurity"/>

        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://www.example.com/HelloWorldService.svc"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

      </service>

    </services>

    <behaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>

        <behavior name="BehaviourMessageSecurity">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
             customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="HelloWorldService.ServiceAuthenticator, HelloWorldService" />
            <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"
                                storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>

       </serviceBehaviors>

    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>

        <binding name="BindingMessageSecurity">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>

      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Czustom means you write your own validation method. If you don't want to check the certificate at all, use None:

> ```
> .ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None
> ```

Comment: I tried that as well as per the other solution just under the heading "Disabling X.509 certificate validation in .NET" in that thread but that didn't work either. I don't mind whether I provide an overridden custom validator that always returns true or whether I use no validation at all. I just want to get this to work.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "does not work"? What error message do you get?

Comment: The exception is "The requested service, 'http://www.example.com/HelloWorldService.svc' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information." There is no inner exception. The service works fine with no security. The only things I have changed are the client credentials above and the security mode (set to UserName). The bindings and behaviors tags match between client and server. I had this working with server and client both on my local machine with dummy certificates made with "make cert".

Comment: Now I am trying to deploy to a remote server. I get the feeling that this error has something to do with either the inability to find a certificate with the subject name "localhost" (as specified in the service's web.config service certificate tag) on the server or with the certificate being invalid. In other words, it's not bypassing the certificate check.

Comment: Could you edit your question and post your server side app.config please?

Comment: I have inserted the web.config above. I have worked out that I can wire the custom certificate validator class on the client with "myServiceClient.ClientCredentials. .ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CustomCertificateValidator = New MyX509CertificateValidator" where MyX509CertificateValidator is a class contain an overriding Validate procedure. I have tried making this Validate procedure throw an exception and not throw an exception but it doesn't seem to be called at any point.

Comment: Okay, I might be wrong here but I do not think this would be a problem with the certificate validation.

Could you debug the server and see what exception is being thrown there? It might help us in finding the actual problem.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. The service is on a remote hosted server.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52105/discussion-between-nxu-and-guru-josh)